Does topological conjugacy hold in the hyperbolic subspace of linearizations?

Suppose you have a nonlinear vector field $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ and a fixed point $\mathbf{x}'$ s.t. $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}') = \mathbf{0}$.
Let $\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}')$ be the linearization of $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ about $\mathbf{x}'$.
If the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ all have non-zero real part, then the fixed point is hyperbolic and the Hartman-Grobman theorem establishes topological conjugacy between the linearization and the nonlinear vector field in the neighbourhood of the fixed point.
If the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ do not all have non-zero real part, then we can apply center manifold theory to get the eigenspaces corresponding the stable (negative real eigen values), unstable (positive real eigenvalues), and center (zero real eigenvalues).
Let the hyperbolic subspace be the subspace spanned by both the positive and negative real eigenvalues.
If I pick a random point in the neighbourhood of the fixed point, project it to the hyperbolic subspace, and integrate the projection of the linearized vector field (projected to the hyperbolic subpsace), will I get a trajectory that is locally conjugate with the original nonlinear vector field (in the hyperbolic subspace)?

I.e. does topological conjugacy hold in the hyperbolic subspace of vector field linearizations?
